# Remove all special characters from a file.

Tags: unix

I have a file with special characters and I only want alpha/numbers back.

File:

```
!12asdfasdf@$!@$%$#@123123%@#$%123
```

Return:

```
12asdfasdf123123123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use `sed` or `awk` for this:

#### Sed

```
sed "s/[^a-z|0-9]//g;" file
```

#### Awk

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")}1' file
```